# In yii how to create confirmation link

Tags: yii, confirmation

In yii, i am creating a project. I want to create link in yii such that it will get send to user by email and when user will click link,`actionCheck` will get called in which this user's id will get retrieved. and password reset page will get render to him for inserting new password.  I also want to pass confirmation random key generated along with link,So that i can retrieve that user's id, So how to create this link?
i had generated it as-

```
$url='http://localhost/Project/index.php?r=User/Check&key=$key'
```

where `$key` is a randomly generate one. 
When i am passing this link to email and clicking it,Its giving an error as-

`"Error 403 You are not authorized to perform this action."`

Please help me.

Comment: www.yiiframework.com, please learn the basics first..:)

add your access rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User controller you can see

```
public function accessRules()
    { ... }
```

add your `actionCheck()` there, with appropriate access rules something similar to below

```
array('allow',  
'actions'=>array('action1','action2',..............,'check'),
'users'=>array('*'),
),
```